# Resharper suggesting readonly field, why?

Tags: c#, resharper

This is my class

```
public class EmailBuilder
    {
        public string Sender { get; set; }
        public string Receiver { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public int SmtpServerPort { get; set; }
        public string SmtpServerAddress { get; set; }

        private MailMessage _mail;

        public EmailBuilder()
        {
            this._mail = new MailMessage();

            this.SmtpServerAddress = CmsConstants.smtpServerAddress;
            this.SmtpServerPort = CmsConstants.smtpServerPort;
        }

        public void SetEmail(string receiver, string subject, string body)
        {
            this._mail.To.Add(receiver);
            this._mail.From = new MailAddress("noreply@noreply.se");
            this._mail.Subject = subject;
            this._mail.Body = body;
            this._mail.Bcc.Add("noreply@noreply.se");
        }
}
```

resharper is suggesting that _mail is to be made readonly, but wouldn't that make so that in my "SetEmail" method that those properties will not be set?
Someone care to explain if I'm misunderstanding something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Readonly means you cannot reassign field itself:

```
_mail = new MailMessage(); // cannot do that outside constructor
```

But that does not mean properties of object itself cannot be modified:

```
_mail.To = new EmailAddress("test"); // perfectly fine with readonly field.
```

So Resharper suggestion is correct - you only assign your field in constructor so it can be made `readonly`.

Comment: So a field that is readonly can have its properties changed wherever? I've always thought that was not the case and could only have its properties changed within the constructor.

Comment: Well what you thought is not true then :)

Comment: @grimsan55 and you should design such object immutable yourself - language has no support out of the box to make objects magically immutable.

Comment: @grimsan55 On the plus side, you haven't done anything 'wrong' as such. Resharper is simply saying that you could change your code to explicitly reflect the coding structure you have written.